PhpStorm showing red line on code where cognitive complexity is high. How to remove it?
In the PhpStorm IDE I am getting a red line on all functions where Cognitive Complexity is high. It is good to be known that there is high cognitive complexity, but in my case it is annoying to see this red line.
I want to remove it. How to do it?
I have latest version of PhpStorm. And using SonarLint plugin, Better Comments plugin and Code Comments plugin with Material UI theme.
I want to remove those red/ping lines which is visible in every line.


The best way: place the caret on one of such lines, invoke the Intentions / Quick Fix menu (Alt+Enter on most keymaps), then expand the submenu of the desired action (in vast majority of cases that would be top most entry) and proceed from there -- disable the inspection, configure it etc.

At quick glance it should be one of the inspections found at Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Refactoring opportunities. You can change the inspection Severity there, or create your own severity (just for that Inspection etc) with custom styling.

Found the solution under following structure. Disabled it.
File
    Settings
        Editor
            Ispections
                Congnitive Complexity
                    High Congnitive Comlexity

